# R-Map with color points depending on the category

Tags: r, ggmap, qmap

I need to create a map with point given by coordinates **but with different colors depending on a variable (let's say 'cat').**

```
data1=data.frame(X=c(-122,-122,-122), Y=c(37,37,38), cat=c('A', 'A', 'B'))
    map <- qmap('San Francisco', zoom = 12, maptype = 'hybrid')
    map + geom_point(data = data1, aes(x = X, y = Y), color="red", size=1, alpha=0.5)
```

I though to introduce color=cat but didn't work.

Comment: Put `color = cat` inside `aes()`, and delete `color = "red"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited your X and Y values so that they're within the map area you selected (you were close, but a little off):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
data1 = data.frame(X = c(-122.4, -122.42, -122.4),
                   Y = c(37.8, 37.8, 37.79),
                   cat = c('A', 'A', 'B'))
map <- qmap('San Francisco', zoom = 12, maptype = 'hybrid')
```

Then I specified, `color = cat` inside `aes()`. I also deleted `color = "red"` outside of aes() as that is contradictory. I also bumped up the size and got rid of the transparency so it's nicely visible.

```
map + geom_point(data = data1, aes(x = X, y = Y, color = cat), size=4)
```

[image]

Works just fine.

Comment: thanks. Do you know why qmap doesn't work inside a loop?

Comment: There's a lot of questions about using `ggplot` in a loop--a lot of ways you can go wrong. I would recommend creating a list of plots and the printing them as separate loops or `lapply` calls. If you're having trouble, ask a new question (or look for other SO questions about ggplot and loops).